# Insert a resolve comment into a cell Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to insert a comment into a cell in Google Spreadsheets. I have the following code which adds notes but it's not what I'm looking for as it doesn't have the resolve option..

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var comments = cell.getComment();
  comments = comments + "\\nLast modified: " + (new Date());
  Browser.msgBox(comments);
  cell.setComment(comments);
}
```

Above gets this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you **cannot** modify comments via Appscript. It's a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1818). You'll have to make due with notes or wait for comments to be fixed/added.

Comment: Open for three years... Ridiculous.